# Run wpcli instead of /usr/bin/env wp

Tags: wordpress, unix, ubuntu, ssh, capistrano

I am using wp-deploy (https://github.com/Mixd/wp-deploy) in order to deploy wordpress.
This run Capistrano 3 and several ssh commands. My host is bluehost. One of the commands it runs over the ssh is:

```
/usr/bin/env wp core install <arguments>
```

Which is wp-cli (http://wp-cli.org/). The thing is that I don't have permission to install wp-cli and I don't have permission to add files to `/usr/bin/env`. But, bluehost do have wp-cli installed under `wpcli` command.
The thing is that Capistrano executes `/usr/bin/env wp core install <arguments>` and I want to change it to `wpcli core install <arguments>`.

I don't know whether this is Capistrano or unix problem / solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue:
1. Download wp-cli wp-cli.phar
2. Put it under ~/bin
3. Add the following SSHKit command map:
`SSHKit.config.command_map[:wp] = "php-cli /path/to/user/home/bin/wp-cli.phar"`